# How to convert a collection of strings into individual strings

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a collection of strings that I need to make into separate strings in order to place them into a MySQL database.

```
SortedSet<String> someSet = new TreeSet<String>():
someSet.add("Name");
someSet.add("Name2");
someSet.add("Name3");
```

How would I go back and get each name separately?  The someSet.toString() reads all of the names into a string, but they aren't separated.  Could someone please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out I believe.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
sql = "INSERT INTO nameBook(name3, name2, name1) " +
      "VALUES( ";
for(String name : nameSet){
    sql = sql.concat(" '" + name + "' , ");
}

sql = sql.concat(")");
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through items in a set either using an explicit [`iterator`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm), or using a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (String item : someSet) {
    System.out.println(item);
    // do whatever you want with the item
}
```

Comment: If you want advice about writing a MySQL command you will need to give some context to what you are doing in MySQL.

Comment: I'm adding a collection of names to the database, but in order to insert the names into the database, I have to get them into singular strings for the INSERT INTO command.  I'm taking input from the UI and setting the strings into the collection, and in the services level, I'm reconverting them back into strings.  I'm not sure if that made sense or I just went around in a circle

Comment: @user2649644 Maybe you should write a new question that includes enough detail about the MySQL for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedSet<String> someSet = new TreeSet<String>();
someSet.add("Name");
someSet.add("Name2");
someSet.add("Name3");

for (String s : someSet) {
    System.out.println(s);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the `someSet`

Option 1

```
SortedSet<String> someSet = new TreeSet<String>();
someSet.add("Name");
someSet.add("Name2");
someSet.add("Name3");
Iterator iterator=someSet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Option 2

```
SortedSet<String> someSet = new TreeSet<String>();
someSet.add("Name");
someSet.add("Name2");
someSet.add("Name3");
for(String i:someSet){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner in case you prefer it

```
System.out.println(someSet.toString().substring(1).replaceAll(", ","\r\n").replace("]",""));
```